# Magento 2 change Mobile Footer background color

Tags: magento2

How can I change the background-color of the footer on mobile devices?
I have changed the background-color of the footer on desktop with "@footer__background-color: #1D1D1D;".

What less variable is for mobile footer background? 
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Please check below file where you can find that place.

1) Here you will find @color-gray-light01: #f4f4f4; defined footer backgroup variable.

> D:\xampp\htdocs\mage21\vendor\magento\magento2-base\lib\web\css\source\lib\variables_colors.less

2) Here you will find @footer__background-color: @color-gray-light01; footer actual class.

> D:\xampp\htdocs\mage21\vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\Magento_Theme\web\css\source_module.less

3) I dont konw about mobile but I think this will update from here

> D:\xampp\htdocs\mage21\vendor\magento\theme-frontend-luma\web\css\source\components_modals_extend.less

Note: Dont forget to override these files in your custom theme and before check/reviewing your change remove var folder first.

I Hope this will help you.